# C++ Part-Of-Speech tagger

Tags: library, software-development, c++, spell-checker

I am, with some friends, developing a serious game about correcting spelling mistakes.
The first version was developed in Java, but we want to start again from scratch, and we decided to use C++/Qt this time.

In this game, we take a text, we create mistakes, and the player needs to correct them, so the mistakes need to be credible. To achieve this with Java, we used [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) (LT) to retrieve the type of each word and insert a mistake into it.

The problem is, LT only works in Java, and **we want to work fully with C/C++ stuff** for efficiency. We just need a **part of speech tagger** (POS), but we failed to find a good one for us. The closest to our needs is probably [YamCha](http://chasen.org/~taku/software/yamcha/) but it's undocumented and has been abandoned since 2005.

Is there any library that does the job, has easy to use POS tagging, is lightweight and written fully in C++? The only ones I found were old or not written in C++. It needs to work with French too, but I suppose every POS tagger does that, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following C++ libraries could do the job:

- [Freeling](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/node/1)
- [MeTA: ModErn Text Analysis](https://meta-toolkit.org/pos-tagging-tutorial.html)
- [TurboParser](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/TurboParser/)
- [nlp-tools](https://github.com/brunexgeek/nlp-tools)
- [lapos](http://www.logos.ic.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tsuruoka/lapos/)
- [CogComp's Natural Language Processing libraries](https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp)

Other links can be found [there](https://github.com/keon/awesome-nlp#user-content-c++).